# Java class storing static data

Tags: java

I have a large amount of static data that I want to store in my code, and I'm not sure the best way to do this. As an example, I want to store some fields like first name, last name, address, and phone number. I want to store this for several different users.

My initial thoughts were that I'd create a class with the fields I want, and then I'd make that class a nested class. I would make the outer class singleton and have an ArrayList of the inner class. I'd then instantiate several copies of the inner class. I feel like this is going to be awful though, because I don't want to instantiate several copies of a class. I want to just have one class with all the information.

Anyone know how I should go about this?

Comment: how "large" is the amount? why you have to store them in source codes?

Comment: Your first inclination seems reasonable. Why are you concerned about creating multiple instances of a class? That is the basis of object oriented languages such as Java.

Comment: @Kent Please have a look at my answer and see if that needs improvement :)

Comment: @Kent - I don't have too much information that I feel it needs to be stored elsewhere. I intend for it to be used very frequently in the code so I think it's best if I store it there.

What I want to do is essentially have a class that has an ArrayList of this information. When I want the information, I will ask that class. Something like: 

person.getAddress("Kent");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got you right. It seems that you want to have a set of constant (immutable) `Person` objects. If it is true, enumeration is the thing you are looking for. You can have something like:

```
enum Person {
        Kent("myLast","Kfirst","kfoo"),
        Someone("sLast", "sFirst", "sfoo");

        private String lastname;
        private String firstname;
        private String foo;

        Person(String lastname, String firstname, String foo) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public String getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }
```

you can get field value by:

```
Person.Kent.getFirstname();
```

I am not sure if I understand you right.

Comment: It was a simple "I can haz ze code pliz" question, I suppose :-/

Comment: Yes, this sounds great. I knew I could make an enum that had a value tied to each item, but not multiple values to each item. Thanks.

Comment: @LittleChild the "static" has confused me too. but after reading the Q twice, I felt OP meant Constant. But I am not sure if enum would work if he had "a large amount" of fields or objects.  the "large" I thought > 10k, that's why I asked the question in comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `inheritance`. You can have a class called `Person` which contains all the fields you want (along with appropriate methods). Then you can have other specialized persons like a `Manager` or what not by `extend`ing that class (If you want to, that is. Or else, you can just instantiate a `Person`).

You use `static` when your data is to be shared among objects of the class. If you have the name and age, say, as static then you will be in hot water. You need them to be non-statics. That way every object will have their own copy of the fields.

Have a look : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: This is not what I want, I do not need inheritance. In fact, what I want IS to have all the information be static. I am using this class just to hold some information for my project, nothing more, nothing less. For each person, who has the fields mentioned above, I want their information to be static.

I also want it to be easily queried from outside, which is to say I would want to do something like:

    person.getAddress("Michael");

Comment: @MichaelYousef I see. However, `the use of the static keyword to create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance of the class.` Why the fascination with static ? :)

Comment: if I do not make anything static, will I not end up creating new copies of the information? I want the information to exist exactly once in the project.

Comment: @MichaelYousef Say there are two people. Dont you think each one will have their own name and age and address? *Different copies* of the same data? :) Each person will be a `Person` object and will hence need non-static variables to hold their name, etc.

Comment: @MichaelYousef With static, however, you will end up overwriting the `name` because only one `name` field will exist and that will be shared by all the objects - be it a one or a million. So a change of name from `Mike` to `Tyke` will cause a change in each of these million names as there is only one copy of `name` and that is shared because u made it static

Answer (score 0):

What about making an interface with all needed constants?

Then every class you want to contain those static values will implement that interface?